# Is it possible that bucketing sink create bucket on event time?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The Document said Bucketer will assigns to buckets based on current system time.

I want to know that if I can assign bucket based on event time?

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be straightforward if you use a StreamingFileSink where I believe this is simply a matter of writing a custom [BucketAssigner](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/filesystem/BucketAssigner.html) that uses the event time to determine the bucket id.

StreamingFileSink was recently added to Flink to solve a number of problems with the BucketingSink. But if you want to stick with the BucketingSink for some reason, I believe you could also easily implement a custom [Bucketer](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/Bucketer.html).